# How to search complete table row by filtering only one column?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4, html-table

I have a table wherein I want to search only the 1st column w.r.t only machine code and if the search matches then it should display the complete row.  Any idea where I am going wrong? Here is the example wherein I have tried but failed: https://jsfiddle.net/xc54qnru/

Tried this script, but was partially successful.

````
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
          $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
      });
    });```
````

Comment: `$("#tabledetails tr")` Your table id is not correct?

Comment: Yes, id was wrong. I have corrected and updated the Fiddle to : https://jsfiddle.net/szxe46ag/

Comment: Actually, you should minify your table data and focus the questions. Your table data is too big to focus the issue. Just remove the unnecessary data.

Comment: @ikhvjs I have not simplified it because that is our requirement. But were you able to get my Qn?

Comment: What I mean is to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you just throw all your codes, no one would try to understand all your codes. Also, you can provide your codes in [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/14032355)

Comment: @ikhvjs Sure will do that and update you !